# Non clustered field length changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've inherited a database in SQL Server 2008 SP3 and have to make some changes to some field lengths in it. Where the field length has increased in a primary key, I can make the change by dropping it then adding it back after.

However, I have a table where it only has a non clustered index, no clustered index or primary key, and one of the field lengths is changing. I made the change whilst commenting out the drop and add sections to see what would happen and expected it to fail but it made the changes.

Is this usual behaviour? If so great, but I was expecting to have to drop and recreate the index even though it is a non clustered one. Should I leave it or should I drop and recreate for best practice?

Thanks very much

Comment: I don't fully understand this question.  As far as I know, SQL Server allows you to modify the length of a column regardless of the columns use in indexes, clustered, primary key, or otherwise.

Comment: Unless the size of index keys does not exceed `900` bytes you are good to go.. Though this limitation has been increased in newer versions

Comment: Thank both. Though apologies after doing a little bit of testing I seem to be getting confused by constraints. I have to drop the constraints then rebuild after. The index I can seem to update regardless if it is a clustered or non clustered if there are no constraints.